# Error during TFS 2012 Upgrade Wizard, Configure the Server Running SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to migrate our existing TFS 2008/SharePoint installation to TFS 2012/SharePoint 2010. If I do it without SharePoint it all works OK, but if I try and include SharePoint it fails.

At the moment I'm starting from scratch and including SharePoint.

I've run the Configure Extensions for SharePoint Products Wizard, restored the TFS 2008 databases, run STSADM from the command line, and now I'm attempting to run the TFS 2012 Upgrade Wizard: it fails at the, Configure the Server Running SharePoint step with the error "TF250004: The SharePoint Products installation is either corrupt or is not valid. Verify that SharePoint Products is a supported version and is functioning properly, and then try again."

Can someone please advise me what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your TFS server can't detect you SharePoint .

Where is your Sharepoint server, is it running on the same computer with TFS server or on another machine?
With your upgrade ,did you change your hardware or use the same hardware as before.

Accroding to your description, you didn't mention whether you need to upgrade your SharePoint. You should finish SharePoint upgrade before your TFS server upgrade.And match **TFS upgrade requirements** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd631912(v=vs.120).aspx

You should also pay attention to your sharepoint permission.I suggest you use a "Full Permission" Account in sharepoint which interact with TFS .For your reference:http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sr/tfsadmin/thread/ea2ef379-dd14-4e23-86e6-fbc156e430d8

Comment: Thanks for your reply Patrick.

Both TFS and SharePoint are on the same computer.

I'm surprised you mention Powershell as none of the documentation I've read or your "TFS upgrade requirements" link mention it.

I've installed SharePoint 2010 but have not configured it in any way, including permissions: I was hoping the TFS 2012 Upgrade Wizard would handle things for me.

Comment: Sorry about my mistake, what i mean is sharepoint. I have modified. About permissions you must make sure the service account that you will use on the upgraded Team Foundation Server is a member of the Farm administrators group.For detail setting you can reference below link from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620926(v=vs.120).aspx   After this, you could retry it.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually unchecked the "Configure SharePoint Products for Use with Team Foundation Server" option to exclude SharePoint during the upgrade and then manually configured SharePoint after the upgrade, overcoming a host of problems along the way.